# node js - Why does my hard coded api request to third party works and why it doesn't when its not hard coded?

Tags: javascript, api, parameters, nodes

I have a route using node js, in which i make an api request to a third party. Ive been testing in in postman and When I hard code the api url insight my route it works. If I don't hard code (please see below) it but just type in params in postman, Im getting an error. Does anybody know why- why is the difference between both routes (hardcoded and not)? Thanks a lot!

doesn't work:

```
        router.get('/testing', function(req,res){
            sampleAPI.get('example/?origin=' + req.query.city + '&name=' + req.query.name + '&xxx=yes&yyy=no&xyx=maybe', function(err, data){
                if (err){
                    res.status(200).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.status(200).send(data);
                }
            })
        })
```

works:

```
        router.get('/testing', function(req,res){
            sampleAPI.get('example/?origin=london&name=myname&xxx=yes&yyy=no&xyx=maybe', function(err, data){
                if (err){
                    res.status(200).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.status(200).send(data);
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: Can you verify what error you're getting and what values are being passed to your non-hardcoded version?

Comment: Most probably you have wrong values in `req.query`, try to examine which values are passed.

Comment: sorry, Im not too familiar with postman and I must have made some mistake when typing in the params, after tons of tries- now it actually started working..

Comment: Between router.get(...) and sampleAPI.get(..) try console.log(req.query), is that undefined?